# Azure DevOps Server object Api get builds by change id

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

With Azure Pipeline object API it is possible to get builds.

```
BuildHttpClient.GetBuildsAsync(params)
```

Now I can get the changes for a build, because I need to filter the builds by a specific change id (commit hash)

```
BuildHttpClient.GetBuildChangesAsync(params, buildId)
// Here I can loop over the changes and search for a specific change id (commit hash)
// But this scales very bad, getting the changes is really slow. Doing this on tousand of builds can take minutes!
```

Is there a way to get builds over the API which has a specific change id in one query?

Answer (score 0):

You could get `sourceVersion` and `id` from `BuildHttpClient.GetBuildsAsync`, and filter `sourceVersion` directly. `sourceVersion` is the changesetId/CommitId. For example:

```
        string _personalAccessToken = "xxxxxxxxx";
        VssBasicCredential credentials = new VssBasicCredential("", _personalAccessToken);
        var connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(@"https://dev.azure.com/xxxx"), credentials);
        var buildServer = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
        var builds = buildServer.GetBuildsAsync($"teamprojectname").Result;

        foreach (var build in builds)
        {
            if (build.SourceVersion == "commitID")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(build.Id);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This would not working reliable for our requirement. If we have more than one commits this wouldn't work anymore. For this, the changeset of a build contains any change with any commit id, and this is exactly what we would need. 
Another point is if we have a top set on GetBuildsAsync arguments, then this would be an additonal filter and wouldnt return the desired number of builds... So we need to load more build until the Top is reached and this is ugly

Comment: If this is the case, I'm afraid you have to loop over the changes as you did before. There is no default way to use api to get builds by change id.